# Apache .htaccess - All URLs with different parameters to ONE redirect

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, apache2, url-parameters

I need some help with .htaccess redirect.

```
http://www.example.de/test-music.html?p1=1&p2[test]=23
http://www.example.de/test-music.html?p1=6&p2[test3]=5
```

ALL of them need to be redirected to ...

```
http://www.example.de/music/
```

... without taking care of any parameters - can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy, this is something you can easily find and figure out yourself.

```
# Check if the url STARTS WITH (is what the ^ does) '/test-music'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test-music
# redirect it, 301 style, Last line (we go away, no need to do the rest of the htaccess)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /music/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Very nice - Thanks! :-) But for me, I had to add a '?' after the last '/' - then all parameters will be deleted ...
RewriteRule ^(.*) /music/? [L,R=301]

Comment: Thats weird, because that isnt the regex part. I don't put the varaibles back in the url (that would mean `$1` would be put there). But hey, if it works!

Comment: Seem that adding a ? after the new URL in the RewriteRule line is what makes the parameters not append to the URL. I think there may be a flag included with apache 2.4 that can be used to also force the removal of parameters as well but I'm not sure of the name of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^test-music\.html$ /music/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: +1, this might be easier. But is a bit more limited, you can't do a `if file doesnt exist` check if someone wants that. Pick whichever suits you better :)